# SonarQube analysis of scss/sass files?

Tags: c#, sass, teamcity, sonarqube

I have a TeamCity-SonarQube setup. I use TeamCity to execute sonar-runner and push the result to a local SonarQube instance. Its a .NET/C# solution and we are moving towards SASS especially SCSS. My current configuration analyzes .cs, .js, and .css files separately using the sonar.language configuration. Is there any support for scss (sass in general). Its an issue since sonarqube does not ingest xml results from jshint, csshint and other lints. I have a SCSS-LINT setup to lint .scss files in my solution but I cant find a SonarQube plugin for scss or any way to integrate the scss-lint result with SonarQube.

My question: Is there a way to analyzes .scss files and display the results in SonarQube as well as configure quality gates etc on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's currently no plugin that we are aware of and that analyzes SCSS files.

Note: Since SonarQube 4.2, multi-language projects are supported so you can analyze your CS, JS and CSS files all at one. See [Analyzing a Multi-Language Project documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Multi-moduleProject).

Comment: scss-lint analyzes scss files. I'm guessing this issue will keep growing as long as sonarqube does not have a standard integration point to ingest results from other types of analyzers. As new formats come up, you will not be able to implement custom code for each of them in time while supporting existing stuff. Its the same story for JSHint, Csshint etc. I know of the multiple language project and I use it (thanks for all you do!) but I'm struggling to keep sonar at the heart of our static analysis. I now need a separate workflow to handle scss and even js.

Comment: @Fabrice, the linked documentation is returning the following message: *The page you're looking for does not exist.*

Answer (score 0):

There is now official support for .scss files in the 3.0 version (released mid January 2017) of the CSS plugin in SonarQube: https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin

*Note: You should probably not use the sonar.language parameter. SonarQube identifies languages used within the project automatically.*